# How to cross-post in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I have two blogs and I would like to cross post some thing from one blog to other. For example if you visit this page http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/get-whole-family-together-over-holidays.html, At the bottom of the post, it says "(Cross-posted on the Gmail Blog)".

Are there some ways I can cross post without duplicating the content?

Comment: Good question. Maybe it's a Google-specific thing, though...

Answer (score 5):

I think that "Cross-posted on the Gmail Blog" on the page you refer to is just another way of saying "Same content also posted on the Gmail Blog".

Some specific platforms (e.g. Usenet) have a built-in mechanism for "cross-posting" (e.g. a way of tagging content so that it shows up in more than one context).  There is no such general mechanisms for the web, or for blogger.  Google *may* have implemented such a mechanism for GoogleBlog and Gmail Blog, but it is just as likely that the guy just copy and pasted his own content between the two blogs.